# order by timestamp without a database?

Tags: php

I have to store some info (timestamp of post, title and link) from various feeds (facebook,twitter,rss and some custom xml) without using a database. So I'm writing what I need to xml files and then pulling everything in using simplexml. This works fine. However, I need output the info from the various feeds in to a un-ordered list that's ordered by the timestamp. I don't know how to do this. I can get the info from each feed aggregated in to one array but how do I order by the timestamp before I output it in to html?

Comment: How does your "timestamp" look like, exactly? Is it in the same format in all feeds you have?

Comment: They're all slighly different formats from each feed but I think I might try use strtotime() to get them all as timestamps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use usort() to sort using user-defined function; the function is pretty simple, it just need to compare the 'timestamp' field of the two arguments given.

Comment: Brilliant. HTis will do it I think. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to store your feeds in array and make the key as `timestamp`, then you can use `krsort()` to sort array from high to low or `ksort()` low to high.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php